# Gesture implying someone is insane

Tags: phrase-request

How do you call the gesture where you point at your head and make a circle or a few with your extended finger - when you want to imply someone, or some idea is "nutters" - something so ridiculous it's insane?

Comment: I'm afraid, there's no single word. You'll have to form a sentence for that.

Comment: @MaulikV: "Phrase request", I believe there is some "canonical" way of describing it.

Comment: Caveat: Gestures are by no means universally understood. This gesture *may* mean "you are crazy", but it *may* also mean "you are clever". A lot depends on cultural context.

Comment: @Stephie: Probably so, but - at least in my culture - knocking your head with your finger there means "clever". A twirl, or twisting your finger ("tightening a loose screw") means insane.

Comment: @SF.: which proves my point: Knock on your forehead or temple in Germany and you may be sued for insult. Do this towards a police officer and find yourself in court. Expect to pay 750€.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures), this gesture is called:

> **Cuckoo sign, touched or screw loose.** In North America, making a circling motion of the index finger at the ear or side of the head signifies that the person "has a screw loose," i.e. is speaking nonsense or is crazy.

---

I will repeat my warning that gestures are rooted in their cultural context and **may mean completely different things** in other cultures.