# Best way to describe this rotating movement with your finger

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the best way to describe the movement you do with your finger when you want to mime something that rotates, such as the spinning rotors of a helicopter? I guess it's the same movement that you do close to your ear when you want to say that someone is not mentally sane.

I looked several words up in the dictionary and ran ngram searches, and these are what I think should be the best, and most usual, ways to do so.

> She twirled her finger in the air.
>
> She twirled her finger around.
>
> She rotated her finger in the air.

My questions are:

- Are these sentences correct? Are there better ways to describe this action?
- Is there a substantial difference between the verb "rotate" and "twirl" in this specific example?
- Is "in the air" better than "around"? Could I omit both or do they add clarity?

Comment: To my ear, "twirl" is not quite right because it implies speed and grace, and I at least do not look like a vision of speed and grace when I rotate my finger. (of course that is true no matter what I do.) I am not saying "twirl" is wrong; it just seems to me that "rotate" or "circled with" are a bit more natural.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52561/gesture-implying-someone-is-insane

Comment: No, because you twirl something that is unconnected to you, unless of course, you are saying twirling a lock of hair with your finger.

Comment: ***twirled*** is fine, but so is [*She **circled** her finger in the air*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circled+her+finger+in+the%2Ctwirled+her+finger+in+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircled%20her%20finger%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwirled%20her%20finger%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0). And that doesn't require you to learn a new word.

Comment: "Twirl your finger" is the right one for the action you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Twirling** or *twiddling*. I'm from Texas where we tend to say

> twiddling yer fingers

A LOT, lol

Rotated? No, I think not. It's not as descriptive; it's easier to get a mental picture of twirling fingers and twiddling than rotating. I disagree with circled bc that's simply making a circle. The act of twiddling/twirling the fingers is more complex and implies more (i.e. twirling your fingers next to your head implies crazy).